# How to allow only one decimal between operators (Calculator app)

Tags: javascript

I've been racking my brain trying to figure out how I can prevent more than one decimal for each number between arithmetic operators. Also, would it be more memory efficient to use event delegation when clicking a button instead of looping and adding event listeners? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
const display = document.querySelector(".result");
const number = document.getElementsByClassName("number-button");
const operator = document.getElementsByClassName("operator-button");
const equals = document.querySelector(".equals-button");
const clear = document.querySelector(".all-clear");
const backSpace = document.querySelector(".backspace");
let state = 0;

function reset() {
  display.value = "";
}

// Iterates through number elements and sets event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < number.length; i++) {
  number[i].addEventListener("click", function() {

    if (state === 0) {
      display.value += parseInt(this.value, 10);
    } else if (state === 1) {
      reset();
      display.value += parseInt(this.value, 10);
      state = 0;
    }

  })
}

// Iterates through operator elements and sets event listeners
for (var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++) {
  operator[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    const prevIndex = display.value.substring(display.value.length - 1);

    // if previous value is an operator, a new clicked operator will replace it
    if (prevIndex === "*" || prevIndex === "+" || prevIndex === "-" || prevIndex === "/" || prevIndex === ".") {
      display.value = display.value.slice(0, -1);
      display.value += this.value;
    } else if (display.value.length > 0) {
      display.value += this.value;
      state = 0;
    }
  })
}

// clears display value
clear.addEventListener("click", function() {
  reset();
})

// deletes previous value on display
backSpace.addEventListener("click", function() {
  display.value = display.value.slice(0, -1);
})

// Evaluates expression on display
equals.addEventListener("click", function() {
  display.value = eval(display.value);
  state = 1;
})
```

Comment: Normally you would write a small scanner and tokenicer. But it seems that's not matching your skill at the moment. In your case it should work if you remember the actual number and check if there is already a decimal or not. The actual number is cleared after an operator. That's it.